# Armature Model Suddenly Big

Tags: armature, bones, scale

I created an armature for my Collada (.dae) model, selected the armature and my model, then applied automatic weights. For some reason, my model suddenly became 20 times larger after applying the weights. I tried removing doubles, using regular parenting, and applying uniform weights, but nothing seems to work. I have been dealing with this issue for quite a while, and the internet has little to no mentioning of the issue (some websites did not have answers). Can anyone help me fix this? I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Try to apply the scale of the armature and the model before generating weights.

Comment: @Denis How can I do that? (Scaling the model also scales the armature)

Comment: ----------> ctrl + A

Comment: It totally works now! Thanks guys! :) I tried to up vote both of your comments, but an error message is displayed.